# What is the difference between the different overriding methods in Scala?

Tags: scala, overriding

Scala lets you override a method in two legal ways:

Given super class:

```
class A {
  def a = "A"
}
```

We can override the method "a" by:

```
class B extends A {
  override def a = "B"
}
```

and

```
class B extends A {
  override def a() = "B"
}
```

both seem to override the method "a" correctly. What is the design decision behind this? Why allow for "a()" in B to override "a" in A?

Comment: `a()` and `a` are both methods named `a` that take no arguments i.e. have arity of zero, i.e. they are identical. Why wouldn't they allow it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This hasn't always been the case (from the change log of [the language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)):

> Scala version 2.0 also relaxes the rules of overriding with respect to
>   empty parameter lists. The revised definition of *matching members*
>   (§5.1.3) makes it now possible to override a method with an explicit,
>   but empty parameter list `()` with a parameterless method, and *vice
>   versa*.

You are correct that this seems like an odd design decision, given that there are observable differences between parameterless methods and ones with empty parameter lists. For example, suppose you have the following:

```
class A { def a = "A" }
class B extends A { override def a = "B" }
class C extends A { override def a() = "C" }
```

Now we can write the following, as expected:

```
scala> (new B).a
res0: java.lang.String = B

scala> (new C).a
res1: java.lang.String = C
```

And this:

```
scala> (new C).a()
res2: java.lang.String = C
```

But not this:

```
scala> (new B).a()
<console>:10: error: not enough arguments for method apply: (index: Int)Char in class StringOps.
Unspecified value parameter index.
              (new B).a()
```

So Scala does make a distinction between the two, which obviously must be reflected in the bytecode. Suppose we compile the following:

```
class A { def a = "A" }
class B extends A { override def a = "B" }
```

And then run:

```
javap -verbose B > noArgList.txt
```

Then change the code to this:

```
class A { def a = "A" }
class B extends A { override def a() = "B" }
```

Recompile, and run:

```
javap -verbose B > emptyArgList.txt
```

And finally check for differences:

```
<   MD5 checksum 88aeebf57b645fce2b2fcd2f81acdbbd
---
>   MD5 checksum 3733b3e4181b4b2f4993503d4c05770e
32c32
<   #18 = Utf8               }1A!
                                 \t\t!ICaT-9uszaE\r)\"a\tI!!\"1Q!Dg
jiz\"a\tAQ!BY\t!Y                                                  G.Y11bU2bY|%M[3di\")C%1A(
                 /A$H3)!dGYtwMCQM^1\nyI\"AB*ue&tw\r
---
>   #18 = Utf8               }1A!
                                 \t\t!ICaT-9uszaE\r)\"a\tI!!\"1Q!Dg
jiz\"a\tAQ!BY\t!                                                   G.Y11bU2bY|%M[3di\")C%1A(
                /A$H3)!dGYtwMCQM^1\nyI\"AB*ue&tw\r
```

So there is a difference—the two versions have different values for the `ScalaSignature` annotation.

As to *why* the change was made in Scala 2.0: the specification notes that it allows this:

```
class C {
    override def toString: String = ...
}
```

My guess is that the language designers just didn't see a reason to require users to remember which approach the overridden methods used in cases like this.

Comment: Since I'm just starting to learn Scala, could you tell me what the ScalaSignature annotation is used for?

Comment: It's a fairly low-level implementionation detail that you shouldn't need to worry about for a long time, [if ever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985096/should-we-use-the-scalasignature-directly). Its role is to allow the Scala compiler to make distinctions like this.